# I have trouble Issues to Login..why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Login.js :

```
const Login = ({history}) => {

  const [userID, setuserID] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error/*, setError*/] = useState("");
  //const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if(localStorage.getItem("userInfo")){
      history.push("/");
    }
  }, [])
  
  
  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    try{
    e.preventDefault();

    const userID = '';
    const password = '';
    
    const token = Buffer.from(`${userID}:${password}`, 'utf8').toString('base64');
    
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate/';
    const data = {
      userID: '',
      password: ''
    }
    
    let result = axios.post(url, data, {
      withCredentials: true,
      
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${token}`
      },
      auth: {
        userID: userID,
        password: password

      }}).then(function(response){
        console.log('Authenticated');
      }).catch(function(error){
        console.log('Error on Authentication');
      })
      
      localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(result) );
    console.log(error);
  }catch(error){
  console.error(error);
  }
  console.log(userID, password);
}



  return <MainScreen title='LOGIN'>
    Eingabe = {`${userID}:${password}`};
    
    <div className="loginContainer">
        {error && <ErrorMessage variant="danger">{error}</ErrorMessage>}
        {/*{loading && <Loading /> }*/}
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          {/*<Form.Group controlId="LoginUserIDInput">*/}
            <Form.Label>userID</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              id="LoginUserIDInput"
              type="text"
              value={userID}
              placeholder="Enter userID"
              onChange={(e) => setuserID(e.target.value)}
            />
           
          {/*</Form></Form.Group>*/}
          {/*<Form.Group controlId="LoginPasswordInput">*/}
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              id="LoginPasswordInput"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              placeholder="Password"
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          {/*</Form.Group>*/}

          <Button id="LoginButton" variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
        <Row className="py-3">
          <Col>
            Not Registered ? <Link to="/register">Register Here</Link>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
  </MainScreen>;
  
}

export default Login;
```

I got these two errors:

```
[Error] TypeError: Not enough arguments — Login.js:56
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (authenticate, line 0)
```

My Login function in backend:

```
exports.login = async (req,res) =>{

  const b64auth = (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || '';
  const [userID, password] = Buffer.from(b64auth, 'base64').toString().split(':');

  const user = await User.findOne({ userID: userID });

  if(!user) return res.status(400).send('User not found');
  const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Incorrect Password');

  const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id, userID: user.userID }, SECRET_KEY);
  req.token = token;
  res.header('Authorization', token).json(token);
  //return res.json({token});
}
```

So my Problem here is tht in the Backend I can give the response

Authorization: Basic admin:123

but here in the frontend it´s not working.
I tried several things but I don´t know what I can do anymore....

I read several internet sites and I have wrote my program that why so I don´t know what I did wrong..

Comment: What's the value of `userID` and `password` on the backend?

Comment: What do you mean ? @IvanRubinson

Comment: The return value of `Buffer.from(b64auth, 'base64').toString().split(':');`

Comment: I think there is no return value it only seperates the given token @IvanRubinson

Comment: If there's no return value then it can't find a user and responds with 'User not found'.

Comment: But it works.. in the backend @IvanRubinson

Comment: You said the server responded with a status of 400

Comment: Yes that´s right... I have same request on backend 

as this :
###
POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate
Authorization: Basic admin:123

and it works